# C# можно ли 10 checkBox описать в цикле?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Закодил 10 сheckBox отдельно и задумался...можно ли описать это циклом?

```
private void checkBox9_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!checkBox9.Checked)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[6].Value = 0;
        dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Pink;
    }
    else if (checkBox9.Checked)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[6].Value = 1;
        dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
    }
}

private void checkBox10_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!checkBox10.Checked)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[6].Value = 0;
        dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Pink;
    }
    else if (checkBox10.Checked)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[6].Value = 1;
        dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вставьте код текстом, а не картинкой. А то отвечающим придется его за вас набирать!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно даже без цикла:

Тот чекбокс, который был чекнут, приходит как `sender`. Данные, специфические для конкретного чекбокса, можно хранить в свойстве `CheckBox.Tag`. Так что можно полностью устранить копипасту.

Проставьте всем чекбоксам значение свойства Tag - 0, 1, 2, 3. Напишите один общий обработчик вида:

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(checkBox.Tag);
    var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[6];
    if (!checkBox.Checked)
    {
        cell.Value = 0;
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Pink;
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.Value = 1;
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
    }
}
```

и выберите его для события `CheckedChanged` для всех чекбоксов.

Вообще сама по себе необходимость вручную добавить на форму 10 чекбоксов - уже признак, что что-то пошло не так. Возможно вам и создание самих чекбоксов, вместе с проставлением `Tag` и подпиской на `CheckedChanged` стоит как-то автоматизировать.

Comment: Спасибо,буду знать на будущее.

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас попробовал так еще: если форма привязывается на класс ViewModel (как в паттерне MVVM), то к свойству класса можно обратиться по его имени. То есть как-то так:

```
class ViewModel
{
    private string _var1;
    public string Var1
    {
        get { return _var1; }
        set { _var1 = value; }
    }

    private string _var2;
    public string Var2
    {
        get { return _var2; }
        set { _var2 = value; }
    }
    private string _var3;
    public string Var3
    {
        get { return _var3; }
        set { _var3 = value; }
    }
}
```

Использовать так примерно (можно, по-моему, проще, через [PropertyName](он еще в INotifyPropertyChanged используется) но я так сразу не вспомнил как это делать.

```
var vm = new ViewModel();

        vm.Var1 = "one";
        vm.Var2 = "two";
        vm.Var3 = "three";

        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)          
            Console.WriteLine(vm.GetType().GetProperty("Var" + i).GetValue(vm));
```

Comment: Ну понятно, что это пример чуть отвлеченный. Вместо string будет bool и сами CheckBox-ы Binding-ом привязаны к соответствующему свойству.

Comment: Спасибо,вы дали мне "пищу для размышлений".

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите. Если у вас чекбоксы не имеют собственного значения, а просто идут «пачкой», то зачем вам давать каждому отдельное имя? Просто положите их все в массив при создании. И создавать можно в принципе тоже циклом.